# stop jquery draggable div going out the background image

Tags: jquery

it goes in the Paint Chip (#cccccc) background when dragging it out of the background image. i don't want it to do that. i want it to prevent going to the Paint Chip (#cccccc) background.

code: (https://jsfiddle.net/2pvs9r3j/)

````
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link href="https://oli.neocities.org/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
    <script>
      $( function() {
    $( "#window" ).draggable();
  } );
    </script>
    <style>

    body {
      background-image: url("https://oli.neocities.org/windows97/images/background.png");
      background-size: cover;
    }
    
    #window {
      background-color: #B9BABD;
      height: 162px;
      width: 404px;
      font-family: 'Normal';
     
    }
    .windowtitle {
      background: rgb(2,0,36);
      background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 35%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
      width: 404px;
      height: 20px;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: white;
      font-family: 'Normal';
    }
    @font-face {
  font-family: 'Normal';
  src: url('https://oli.neocities.org/windows97/fonts/normal.ttf')  format('truetype');
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="window">
  <div class="windowtitle">
  <p>System</p>
  </div>
  </div>

  </body>
</html>```
````

Comment: You want to prevent the user from dragging `System` div outside of the view?

Comment: yeah...........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
$('').draggable({containment:"#"});
```

Inside `containment:"#"` add the ID of the backgroud image that you want.

Attribution for @Romain in (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14319039/14945696).

Comment: what background image ID? the URL or CSS?

Comment: @Del841 Like this `<img src="" id="TestID"/>`

Comment: yeah but it's in css, so I need a CSS id

Comment: it appears below the image or up the image.... if i drag it to the image then it dosen't go there anymore, which is good...

Comment: yeah. i fixed some things, while searching in google for anwsers. https://oli.neocities.org/windows97/ now the font is glitched, and the title is not on top.

Comment: So why the font is glitched. rollback to my code. which is good without glitch. :)

Comment: @Del841 Also please click on grey check mark next to my answer. :)

Comment: @Del841 Glad to help. :)